Can a Swift user-defined Type be named `Type`?
I'd like to create an enum (or class, or struct) named Type in one of my objects.
This object name cannot be typed normally, as it "conflict with the 'foo.Type' expression".
However, like other reserved keywords, it does compile if typed with backticks.
struct Foo {
    
//  enum Type { } //ERROR: Type member must not be named 'Type', since it would conflict with the 'foo.Type' expression
    
    enum `Type` { // Compiles with backticks...
        case a
        case b
    }
    
    func test() {
        let x = Foo.Type.a // ERROR: Type 'Foo.Type' has no member 'a'
        let y = Foo.Type   // ERROR: Expected member name or constructor call after type name
        let z = Foo.Type.self // ok
    }
}

Trying to use my Type, though, results in the errors above and still seems to conflict with the built-in Type expression. Namespacing the Type does not seem to work.
Can the name Type be used to name a user's Swift object?
If not, why does enum `Type`  compile?

It's not about fixing your issue, but I tend to use Kind when I want to name something Type to avoid confusion.

A very long time ago, this has been reported as a bug, which is still not resolved.

It works for me if you declare a variable using a type annotation including the backticks.
Type inference also seems to work if you type Type.a with or without backticks. But not if you use Foo.Type.a with or without backticks.
struct Foo {
    
    enum `Type` {
        case a
        case b
    }
    
    func test() {
        let c: Type = .a       // ok
        let d: `Type` = .a     // ok
        let e: Foo.Type = .a   // ERROR: Type 'Foo.Type' has no member 'a'
        let f: Foo.`Type` = .a // ok

        let g = Type.a         // ok
        let h = `Type`.a       // ok
        let i = Foo.Type.a     // ERROR: Type 'Foo.Type' has no member 'a'
        let j = Foo.`Type`.a   // ERROR: Type 'Foo.Type' has no member 'a'
        
        let k = Type           // ERROR: Expected member name or constructor call after type name
        let l = Type.self      // ok
    }
}

